Laravel Strict Mode mysql connection
My answer related to laravel
I have table in mysql. I came across that some columns I didn't pass while inserting. how mysql accept inserting those records without throw exception?
enter image description here
those are the columns which added zero value to them when I have inserted rows without passing value to them.
This is the table schema
create table if not exists ads_sliders
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(191) not null,
    image varchar(191) not null,
    appearance_time int default 0 null,
    active tinyint(1) default 1 not null,
    `default` tinyint(1) default 0 null,
    first_period_sort int default 99 null,
    second_period_sort int default 99 null,
    third_period_sort int default 99 null,
    internal_link varchar(191) null,
    external_link varchar(191) null,
    deleted tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    country_id char(36) not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    start_date date not null,
    end_date date not null,
    ad_appears smallint default 1 null,
    display_period int unsigned not null,
    repetition int unsigned not null,
    display_place tinyint not null,
    on_click_action tinyint not null,
    data json null,
    constraint ads_sliders_country_id_foreign
        foreign key (country_id) references countries (id)
            on delete cascade
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

This is the inserting statement
    insert into
  `ads_sliders` (
    `name`,
    `image`,
    `country_id`,
    `end_date`,
    `updated_at`,
    `created_at`
  )
values
  (
    'sadf',
    'assets/images/ads_sliders/cLZVRNXf0LAP4j3IsdLImZejouAEri0grvEJxB0S.png',
    '55af3f40-23e3-11e9-acdc-efd87e16b684',
    '2024-04-30',
    '2024-04-30 09:16:07',
    '2024-04-30 09:16:07'
  )

I have double checked that those columns not null and does not have defalut value. and I made sure that global sql_mode variable value is defalut which is ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION. The mysql version is 8.0.
I test it in a new database schema. and it's working correctly.
enter image description here

you can't skip columns that are not null and have no default value afaik.

that's right but how mysql accept inserting those rows without thrown exception @BagusTesa

You haven't said how you are inserting. Given the image, it looks like you might be inserting from a CSV. What do those columns look like in the CSV?

Include your table schema and your insertion statement.

I added the table's schema and insertion statement @Rogue

@JonWaterhouse It's just an insertion statement. I used normal ORM to insert rows not throw CSV

The code you've shared does not look related to PHP or Laravel - please remove these tags, or share the code that you are really using

I add in bold color that my answer related to laravel project @NicoHaase. Thank you

You still haven't shared how your question relates to Laravel. Also, answers should be posted in  the answer section

I'm sorry it's Laravel issue. I tested it while the request executed.
enter image description here
while request executed somewhere the sql_mode var changed in the session stage.
I you went to database.php config file inside the mysql connection you will see that there is strict mode.
If you turn it off. Whenever laravel make any connection to database it will change the sql_mode to be NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.
in this case any missed value from inert statment will ignored.

This is not an answer to your question.  If you think it's new info to your question, then please use edit to add it to the question.

yes, sorry I know and I re-write the answer. @Luuk

In MySQL, if you attempt to insert a row into a table without specifying a value for every column, the database will handle it in one of the following ways:

Default Values: If a column has a default value defined, MySQL will use that value for the column if no value is provided during the insert operation.
Nullable Columns: If a column allows NULL values and no value is provided during the insert operation, MySQL will insert NULL into that column.
Implicit Conversion: MySQL may also perform implicit data type conversion if the value being inserted can be converted to the appropriate data type for the column.
Strict SQL Mode: If the SQL mode is set to strict, MySQL will throw an error if you attempt to insert a row with missing values for columns that don't allow NULL and don't have a default value.

So, if you're seeing records being inserted without explicitly providing values for all columns, it's likely due to one of these reasons. You can check the column definitions in your table schema to see if default values are defined or if columns allow NULL values. Additionally, you can check the SQL mode to see if it's set to strict or not.
Not allowing nullable value and not declaring a default value is not a very common practice. Defining these depends on the specific requirements of your application and the nature of the data you're dealing with. But I do recommend declaring a default value when you do not allow null and also do not pass a value when inserting.

more info here: Implicit Default Handling. "If a data type specification includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as follows: ....."

I added the table schema and the insertion statement you can see it.
and I checked the sql mode. that's why it's confusing me.
I want to understand the reason.

@abdulrahmansouda can you run the following query: ALTER TABLE ads_sliders MODIFY COLUMN start_date DATE NOT NULL; and then try again? When you do not allow NULL and do not give a value in the INSERT statement mySQL should give an error.

I found the solution Thank you very much. it's laravel frame work issue. @Jeremy
